# How come I can make the expression $(a+b)/c$ equal anything?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I have the following expression:

$$(a+b)/c$$

Where $a=1$, $b=2$ and $c=3$. I can show that it equals 1 easily:

$1=(a+b)/c$

$c*1=c*(a+b)/c$

$c=a+b$

$c-a=a+b-a$

$b=c-a$

Substituting $c-a$ back in for b:

$1=(a+c-a)/c = (a-a+c)/c = (0+c)/c$

$c/c=1$

Now lets say I don't know the values for a, b and c (but they are still the same), but I am trying to see if I can prove the equation equals 7:

$7=(a+b)/c$

$c*7=c*(a+b)/c$

$7c=a+b$

$7c-a=a+b-a$

$b=7c-a$

Substituting $7c-a$ back in for b:

$7=(a+7c-a)/c = (a-a+7c)/c = (0+7c)/c$

$7=7c/c$

$7=7$

What am I missing here? Why can I show that the equation equals both 1 and 7 (and any number really)?

Comment: A false statement implies anything. You shouldn’t be starting out with the thing that you’re trying to derive.

Comment: Because there are infinite values of $a,b,c,n$ such that $\frac{(a+b)}{c} = n .$

Comment: Assuming that the ratio is $7$ you proved that $7=7$.That proves absolutely nothing at all! You cannot conclude that what you started with is correct simply becasue $7=7$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In part 1 you show that IF $(a+b)/c=1$ THEN $c/c=1.$

In part 2 you show that IF $(a+b)/c=7$ THEN $7=7.$

In each part you present a series of equations. How are the ones within each part related to each other? Is each one related to the next by "$\implies$" or by "$\iff$" ? It matters. These are the "connective tissue" that link the bones (the various equations) together. Write the CORRECT connectors in.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be missing is that, assuming $\,c\ne 0,\,$
 the equation
$$ x = (a+b)/c \tag{1}$$
is algebraically **equivalent** to the equation
$$ b = xc-a. \tag{2}$$
This means exactly that if equation $(1)$ is true
then equation $(2)$ is true and vice versa. Also,
if equation $(1)$ is false then equation $(2)$ is
false and vice versa.